# How to change SharePoint server that connected to TFS and recreate all TFS sites there

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, server-farm, tfs, troubleshooting, maintenance

We installed two of them integrated together. Now the last SharePoint server is down and we decide to change the SharePoint server that's connected to TFS.

We want to recreate SharePoint TFS Sites?

How we can move the sites? How we recreate/move each TFS site with documents and contents on it?